# Microsoft Unity - Is it possible to change the registered type at runtime?

Tags: unity-container

I am currently using Unity with MOQ to do my unit testing for WCF. In the application's code, I have the following:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
.....
.....
    _proxy = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration().Resolve<IMyInterface>();
.....
}
```

In the application's app.config, I have the following:

```
<container>
  <register type="IMyInterface" mapTo="MyActualObject" />
</container>
```

In the unit test's app.config, I replace that with my mock object implementation of the proxy.

```
<container>
  <register type="IMyInterface" mapTo="MyMockObject" />
</container>
```

That is all working fine. But what I would like to do further is for certain tests, I would like to replace MyMockObject with a different mock object implementation.

Is it possible to change the registered type at runtime? I have tried modifying the application config during runtime but it fails to detect the change.

```
 Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
 var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)appConfig.GetSection("unity");
 section.Containers[0].Registrations[0].MapToName = "AnotherMockObject";
 appConfig.Save();
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like modifying the config file at runtime would work. I just needed to refresh the section so that the configuration is not cached using ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("unity"). But is this the only way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible.

You can configure Unity as many times as you want. If there's a conflict the most recent definition wins.

In your case if you want to make a runtime change, use the fluent API instead of the config file. Try something like this:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, AnotherMockObject>();

// use AnotherMockObject
_proxy = Resolve<IMyInterface>();
```

The documentation for [Registering Types and Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#registertype_mapping)

Comment: But the code to initialize the container is in the application code and not in the unit tests. I would like to change the type in the unit test itself and I don't think doing RegisterType on a container would apply the same change to all containers.

Comment: It sounds like the application isn't using Unity correctly. There should be a single "root" unity instance that resolves all the objects. The classes that are being injected should not be creating Unity (or preferably not even aware of it). They should be getting the dependency through constructor or property injection.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of what you mean? And how does the unit test have control of the type?

Comment: Google is your friend. The 2 min search gave me: Composition Root - http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx. If you have the time his book really is worth it. Also Dependency Injection for Loose Coupling - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13831/Dependency-Injection-for-Loose-Coupling which even starts talking about mocks.

Comment: Special note... not all registrations will cause overrides. I'm encountering a problem now where registering a type with an injection factory does not replace a registration created via `RegisterType<T1, T2>()`.